# Git: Check out all files that ever existed in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout

Is there a way to check out all files that EVER existed in a git subdirectory?

(newer ones may overwrite older ones...)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to list the names of all the files that were ever added:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A <some-directory> | \
  sort -u > /tmp/files.txt
```

Now you can checkout each one:

```
while read f; do git checkout "$f"; done < /tmp/files.txt
```